# If I write a code and release it under GPL 2.0 (or other license) do I have to follow it myself?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I know that since I own the code rights [I can change the license in a newer version](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178902/if-i-release-a-program-under-gpl-do-i-have-to-continue-to-do-so). But does it mean that while it's under GPL I have to comply with it myself? Or can I do whatever I want with it? Like not disclosing the source or stating changes I committed after.

Comment: It is, didn't find it. Thank you very much.

Comment: FWIW, it took me a bit to find it too... and I'm familiar with the site.

Comment: Haha glad to hear that.